# How to add code in mobile application build in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, mobile, java-me, j2mepolish, netbeans6.7

I have made a mobile application using net-beans, now i want to add my code in that application but its not working, this is my first mobile application please help me out.

Comment: What error Net-beans showing?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question so i can help you in this problem.